# MySql Query optimizer

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, cost-based-optimizer

If I have a query like this

```
select * from student 
inner join courses on courses.id = student.course_id
where student.gpa >= 3.0
order by student.gpa
limit 50;
```

How would Mysql execute this query to optimize the cost?

Comment: Run an explain and mysql will tell you.

Comment: What would the answer that would satisfy you look like?

Comment: You can use EXPLAIN to see the estimated execution plan, and EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see the actual execution plan.

Comment: In what flow query would be executed would join be first or where clause would run first?

Comment: @P.Salmon - EXPLAIN will tell you what it is doing, but not what could be changed to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The following index might help:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON student (gpa, course_id);
```

This index would cover the `WHERE` clause, allowing MySQL to discard any records with a GPA less than 3.0.  In addition, it covers the join.

Comment: why would student table be smaller than courses table. If this is a university database then definitely student will be greater. But thanks for the tip on creating index on where clause column and foreign key.

Comment: Furthermore, that index will cover the `ORDER BY`, thereby letting it get to the `LIMIT` -- hence it will touch only 50 rows (and not do a sort).  Table size and FK are not relevant here.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql